# How to substitute a for-loop with vecorization acting several thousand times per data.frame row?

Tags: performance, r, for-loop, vectorization

Being still quite wet behind the ears concerning R and - more important - vectorization, I cannot get my head around how to speed up the code below.

The for-loop calculates a number of seeds falling onto a road for several road segments with different densities of seed-generating plants by applying a random propability for every seed.
As my real data frame has ~200k rows and seed numbers are up to 300k/segment, using the example below would take several hours on my current machine.

```
#Example data.frame
df <- data.frame(Density=c(0,0,0,3,0,120,300,120,0,0))
#Example SeedRain vector
SeedRainDists <- c(7.72,-43.11,16.80,-9.04,1.22,0.70,16.48,75.06,42.64,-5.50)

#Calculating the number of seeds from plant densities
df$Seeds <- df$Density * 500

#Applying a probability of reaching the road for every seed
df$SeedsOnRoad <- apply(as.matrix(df$Seeds),1,function(x){
    SeedsOut <- 0
    if(x>0){
        #Summing up the number of seeds reaching a certain distance
        for(i in 1:x){
            SeedsOut <- SeedsOut +
                ifelse(sample(SeedRainDists,1,replace=T)>40,1,0)
        }
    }
    return(SeedsOut)
})
```

If someone might give me a hint as to how the loop could be substituted by vectorization - or maybe how the data could be organized better in the first place to improve performance - I would be very grateful!

**Edit:** Roland's answer showed that I may have oversimplified the question. In the for-loop I extract a random value from a distribution of distances recorded by another author (that's why I can't supply the data here). Added an exemplary vector with likely values for SeedRain distances.

Comment: A small aside: in `if(x > 0)`, `x` is a vector, so that probably isn't doing what you intended. Also, if all your data is numeric, sticking to matrices rather than data frames is often a good idea if you're dealing with performance issues.

Comment: @joran `x` wont be a vector as the entire input is a 1 column matrix and `apply()` is run over the rows.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Ah, thanks. I read too quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is generate the `sample()` for all `Seeds` per row of `df` in a single go.

Using `set.seed(1)` before your loop-based code I get:

```
> df
   Density  Seeds SeedsOnRoad
1        0      0           0
2        0      0           0
3        0      0           0
4        3   1500         289
5        0      0           0
6      120  60000       12044
7      300 150000       29984
8      120  60000       12079
9        0      0           0
10       0      0           0
```

I get the same answer in a fraction of the time if I do:

```
set.seed(1)
tmp <- sapply(df$Seeds, 
              function(x) sum(sample(SeedRainDists, x, replace = TRUE) > 40)))

> tmp
 [1]     0     0     0   289     0 12044 29984 12079     0     0
```

For comparison:

```
df <- transform(df, GavSeedsOnRoad = tmp)
df

> df
   Density  Seeds SeedsOnRoad GavSeedsOnRoad
1        0      0           0              0
2        0      0           0              0
3        0      0           0              0
4        3   1500         289            289
5        0      0           0              0
6      120  60000       12044          12044
7      300 150000       29984          29984
8      120  60000       12079          12079
9        0      0           0              0
10       0      0           0              0
```

The points to note here are:

1. try to avoid calling a function repeatedly in a loop if you the function is vectorised or can generate the entire end result with a single call. Here you were calling `sample()` `Seeds` times for each row of `df`, each call returning a single sample from `SeedRainDists`. Here I do a single `sample()` call asking for sample size `Seeds`, for each row of `df` - hence I call `sample` 10 times, your code called it 271500 times.
2. even if you have to repeatedly call a function in a loop, remove from the loop anything that is vectorised that could be done on the entire result after the loop is done. An example here is your accumulating of `SeedsOut`, which is calling `+()` a large number of times.

   Better would have been to collect each `SeedsOut` in a vector, and then `sum()` that vector *outside* the loop. E.g.

   ```
   SeedsOut <- numeric(length = x)
   for(i in seq_len(x)) {
     SeedsOut[i] <- ifelse(sample(SeedRainDists,1,replace=TRUE)>40,1,0)
   }
   sum(SeedOut)
   ```
3. Note that R treats a logical as if it were numeric `0`s or `1`s where used in any mathematical function. Hence

   ```
   sum(ifelse(sample(SeedRainDists, 100, replace=TRUE)>40,1,0))
   ```

   and

   ```
   sum(sample(SeedRainDists, 100, replace=TRUE)>40)
   ```

   would give the same result if run with the same `set.seed()`.

There may be a fancier way of doing the sampling requiring fewer calls to `sample()` (and there is, `sample(SeedRainDists, sum(Seeds), replace = TRUE) > 40` but then you need to take care of selecting the right elements of that vector for each row of `df` - not hard, just a light cumbersome), but what i show may be efficient enough?

Comment: awesome and also a bit shaming, thanks a lot. It never occured to me to fit the amount of samples to the sum of seeds. Will try to look into your "cumbersome" solution once my head has cleared up a bit, for now the explanations you supplied are definitely helpful enough. Good job!

Answer (score 5):

This should do about the same simulation:

```
df$SeedsOnRoad2 <- sapply(df$Seeds,function(x){
  rbinom(1,x,0.6)
})



#   Density  Seeds SeedsOnRoad SeedsOnRoad2
#1        0      0           0            0
#2        0      0           0            0
#3        0      0           0            0
#4        3   1500         892          877
#5        0      0           0            0
#6      120  60000       36048        36158
#7      300 150000       90031        89875
#8      120  60000       35985        35773
#9        0      0           0            0
#10       0      0           0            0
```

Comment: (+1) `rbinom(.., 0.6)` very nice catch

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, had to update the question a bit; what I conclude from your answer is that it would be much better to define a function based on the probabilities (which are currently stored as a vector) and apply that function like you did with `rbinom`.

Comment: @sir_husefugg This is exactly right.  In any simulation, you want to be generating the input data rather than sampling from a data pool.  Generating the data (and having the outputs be consistent with observed data) demonstrates that you have a strong theoretical framework for describing your system and adds validity to extrapolated scenarios.

Comment: `rbinom` is already vectorised wrt `size`: the `sapply` is unnecessary

Comment: @hadley looked at docs and tried it. I think you are mistaken.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm not: `apply(replicate(1000, rbinom(2, c(1, 9), 0.6)), 1, max)`

Comment: Ahh, I see. I expected an output of length 2 (e.g., a matrix) for n=1. Thanks.